# Which is better for efficiency? variabels for repeated selectors or more concise selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I'm trying to use variables to store static selectors I use more than once in a specific scope.

- These vars would be global variables in that they as all the function definitions and event listeners are directly in jquery's `$(function(){ });` scope.
- I could make some singular items ids, which I believe is the fastest selector, although too many ids can be bad and don't serve when more than one element needs to be selected.
- For any non class nor id (rare), I'm using slightly more complex selectors in jQuery or as js traversing the DOM.

For efficiency, is it best to store all repeated selectors in the highest scope where they will be needed, not always global, or for some of the quicker ones like IDs and Classes, should I make new selectors each time?

I've noticed and heard that tagName selectors can be inefficient, should I give those IDs/classes or make a tagName selector once, store it in a var and use that var repeatedly.

This is only concerning static elements and changes to the DOM would require a new selector to include the new elements.

Comment: Caching is always better, if I understand what you mean. So `var selected = $("#selected")` will always be better than selecting it with jquery every day. https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/10-ways-to-instantly-increase-your-jquery-performance--net-5551

Comment: Are you sure, that you already have the concern of speed? Maybe its a case of premature optimization.

Comment: @xDreamCoding Speed isn't a huge issue. But there are some improvements that can be made. If a project is finished, I believe all improvements should be made in the deployed version.

Comment: @A.Lau Thank you, even if those vars are in a higher scope? Please write this as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caching is always better. So `var selected = $("#selected")` will always be better than selecting it with jquery every time `$("#selected").doSomething()`.

From: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/10-ways-to-instantly-increase-your-jquery-performance--net-5551

As for storing it in higher scope, the efficiency/speed probably depends how often its called. So if it's used lots, put it in higher scope.